# Problem Installing express-generator On Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, npm, 20.10

I have Graal JVM installed on Ubuntu 20.10.

I tried installing express-generator, but I got this error message:

```
$ npm install -g express-generator
bash: /usr/lib/jvm/graalvm/bin/npm: No such file or directory
```

Indeed, there is no `npm` directory.

I'd like to remove graal and try reinstalling or using another JVM.

It doesn't appear if I search for the package using `dpkg --list`.

Does this mean I can simply remove the `/graal` folder without causing harm?

Update:

After seeing the accepted answer, I removed Graal from the PATH, deleted the Graal folder from `/usr/lib/jvm`, and changed my default to OpenJDK 13.

Once I did that the express-generator install ran perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you could directly remove its folder. But put back `JAVA_HOME` & `PATH` as it changed them on installation. From:

- https://www.graalvm.org/docs/getting-started-with-graalvm/linux/

There could be other folders check what was extracted from `<graalvm-archive>.tar.gz`. If you still have it.

Comment: Thank you.  Your answer helped me with part of my problem: I realized that I'd set the PATH in my .bashrc to point to Graal.  Once I removed it I was able to change the version of Java.  I see a path to .NET /tools, but I can't tell where it comes from.  Any hints?

Comment: You welcome, .NET ! Have you installed Mono or its IDE before?

Comment: Yes, I installed JetBrains Rider.

Comment: @duffymo, That's could be the one put it there, if you still use it leave there.